# Null sessions in Tomcat7 manager

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

In tomcat sessions manager, there is some empty sessions without name (guessed user name) and i want delete this sessions with a smaller timeout then the normal sessions, how can i do this in my SessionListener class ?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know.

`org.apache.catalina.manager.util.SessionUtils#guessUserFromSession` take as parameter an objet implementing `org.apache.catalina.Session`, for example `org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession`.

`org.apache.catalina.Session#guessUserFromSession` call
`org.apache.catalina.Session#getPrincipal` on this object, which returns an object implementing `java.security.Principal`.

This interface have `java.security.Principal#getName`  `java.security.Principal#toString` for methods to "guess" the user name bound to a session.

If no implementation of `java.security.Principal` is returned
(*null*) `org.apache.catalina.Session` call
`org.apache.catalina.Session#getAttribute` on the following attributes with the following syntax *Login*, *User*, *userName*, *UserName*,
*Utilisateur*, then in lowercase, then in uppercase until it gets a value.

If those attributes are `null`, `org.apache.catalina.Session` iterate over
`org.apache.catalina.Session#getAttributeNames` to find objects implementing `java.security.Principal` or that inherits from 
`javax.security.auth.Subject` to call gain on those objects the methods `#getName`
and `#toString` to "guess" the username bound to this session.

You can do the same process to configure your session timeout.